# How to get raw value which ee.Image.arrayLengths() return?

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I follow an example to learn Time Series Linear Regression. I want to know how to get the shape of ee.Image.
I've learned in the official website documentation before that I can get the shape like this:

```
function getArr(arrImg){
  return arrImg.sample(ee.Geometry.Point([0,0]),1).first().get('array');
}
var a = ee.Image([ee.Array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]),ee.Array([[7,8,9],
[10,11,12]])]).rename(['B1','B2']);
var b = a.toArray(1);
var res = b.arrayArgmax();
print(getArr(res));
print(getArr(b.arrayDimensions()));
```

output:

```
[1,5]
2
```

But when I try to apply this method in ee.Image from a dataset. It doesn't work.

```
var lai = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD15A2H').select("Lai_500m").filterDate("2021-01-01","2022-01-01");

function getArr(img){
  return img.sample(ee.Geometry.Point([0,0]),1).first().get('array');
}

var arr = lai.toArray();
var arrlength = arr.arrayLength(0);
print(getArr(arrlength));
```

output error

```
ComputedObject (Error)
    Element.get: Parameter 'object' is required.
```

What does the value returned by array Length look like, and how to display it？